# How to retrieve the head of a html document using YQL?

Tags: yql, html-head

I'm curious if this is possible at all since a "select * from html" query only returns the body of the document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found the answer. (**EDIT :** thanks to Salathe on the YQL forums!)

```
select * from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com" and xpath='/html/head/title'
```